# Is there ANY possible way to disable HOVER in swMenu for Joomla?

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

I'm talking either a setting in the component or a CSS/JS hack. I've tried both but have failed. Why is this not a standard feature?

Ideally i'd just want the background color to be disabled on hover, and the font color change to remain, but even disabling ANY kind of hover is proving to be a big mystery! Does anybody know how to do this? It's surprisingly absent from google searches...

Comment: Why not set the hover color in CSS to match the background or transparent?

Answer (score 0):

SwMenuPro is a commercial product. If this is not a standard feature, then you should notify the developer so that you receive proper support.